# Infinite carousel in Jetpack Compose with element overlay

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, carousel, android-jetpack

I need infinite carousel as on image:
[image]

I tried:

1. https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/ 
   Deprecated and dont element overlay
2. Use VerticalPager but I get
   [image]

   or
   [image]

   Code:

```
VerticalPager(
    state = horizontalState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(110.dp).padding(start = 16.dp, top = 22.dp, end = 16.dp),
    pageSize = PageSize.Fixed(70.dp)
) { page ->
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .zIndex(page * 10f)
            .graphicsLayer {
                val startOffset =
                    ((horizontalState.currentPage - page) + horizontalState.currentPageOffsetFraction).absoluteValue

                val scale = 1f - (startOffset * 0.15f)
                scaleX = scale
                scaleY = scale
            }
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
    ) {/*item*/}
```

3. Use LazyColumn but it not work like image and not stopped on item as ViewPager
   [image]

   Code:

```
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(110.dp)
    ) {
        val halfHeight = constraints.maxHeight / 2

        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            items(
                count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                itemContent = { globalIndex ->
                    val page = globalIndex % movies.size
                    val scale by remember {
                        derivedStateOf {
                            val currentItem = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == globalIndex } ?: return@derivedStateOf 0.85f
                            (1f - minOf(1f, abs(currentItem.offset + (currentItem.size / 2) - halfHeight).toFloat() / halfHeight) * 0.25f)
                        }
                    }

                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(70.dp)
                            .scale(scale)
                            .zIndex(page * 10f)
                    ) {/*item*/}
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/animated-carousel-with-jetpack-compose-7406a5a2b246) article

Comment: @GurgenArustamyan Unfortunately, this article does not have anything that can help me. I tried all from article in method 2 but it did not give the expected result.